An inequality for Lebesgue measure
$E\subset [a,b]$ is measurable. $I_k\subset [a,b](k=1,2,\cdots)$ are open intervals satisfying: $m(I_k\cap E)\ge \frac23 |I_k|, k=1,2,\cdots$ Prove: $$m\left(\left(\bigcup_{k=1}^\infty I_k\right)\cap E\right)\ge \frac 13 m\left(\bigcup_{k=1}^\infty I_k\right).$$
I'm not sure how to solve this problem. I tried to find a open cover to estimate the measure, but the inequality is always in a wrong direction. How could I solve this?
